# Unable to get console input mode - 0x80070006

Tags: c#, handle, microsoft-bits

I am working on bitsadmin for downloading the files in the network.
I created process for running bitsadmin job creation, addjob, resume, etc.
Application works fine with windows 7 but when i run my exe on xp machine bits give exception as

> BITSADMIN version 2.0 [ 6.6.2600.2180 ]
>   BITS administration utility.
>   (C) Copyright 2000-2004 Microsoft Corp.
>
> Unable to get console input mode - 0x80070006
>    The handle is invalid.

but on xp machine when i create job using command prompt then it works.
What can be the problem???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution instead of using process for bitsadmin I used "SharpBITS.Base" to download the file.